# AngularJS: rendering a component from within the template of another component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to learn angularjs and struggling with getting my second component, 'list, to render. Is something wrong with the syntax? Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS - ViralPatel.net</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>
  <app></app>
  <script src="App.js"></script>
  <script src="List.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's App.js

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.component('app', {

  template:
    '<div>' +
      '<h1>Hello from App.js</h1>' +
      '<list></list>' +
    '</div>'

})
```

And here's List.js, the one that won't render:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.component('list', {

  template:
    '<h1>Hello from List.js</h1>'
    '<ul>' +
      '<li>1</li>' +
      '<li>2</li>' +
    '</ul>'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you're re-declaring the `myModule` module twice. 
The module is being re-declared twice in each of your .js files, when you do the following:

`angular.module('myModule', [])`

A subtle "gotcha" in angular is that a new module is declared internally in AngularJS when you pass `[]` as an second argument to `angular.module` ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval))

Try revising your `List.js` to this and see if that helps:

```
/* Remove the [] to prevent myModule from being re-defined. 
   We assume myModule has been defined during the execution of App.js, 
   which should happen before List.js is executed */
angular
.module('myModule') 
.component('list', {

  template:
    '<h1>Hello from List.js</h1>'
    '<ul>' +
      '<li>1</li>' +
      '<li>2</li>' +
    '</ul>'
})
```

Comment: Thanks that helped (and I noticed a missing + in the template, afterwards). So now renders on the screen but I do get an error in the console that says "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule" .      Edit: nevermind, fixed that bug after following the link in the error. Thanks!